# How to add rejson Python module to existing Redis container

Tags: python, docker, redis, redisjson

I am using a Docker container of Ubuntu, Redis and Python+Flask. I want to also use Redis rejson module in this container but don't know how to combine the two since RedisJSON is (probably only) run via its Docker container. 
I tried to just import rejson python module in my existing container but Docker console results in "ImportError: No module named rejson".

I tried to build such a container via this Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD python app.py
```

And requirements.txt is:

```
flask
redis
requests
rejson
```

But that resulted again in "ImportError: No module named rejson"

I managed to use rejson in a container of its own but now my goal is to combine it with other container. Any ideas?

Comment: Some code? Dockerfile?

Comment: Sure. See edits.

Comment: @Guy_g23 did you managed to solve it?

Comment: No but I did not try much.